# Integer.toString(argument) or toString(argument)

Tags: java, class, object, tostring

I've written up some code for a Credit card class, pasted below. I have a constructor that takes in the said variables, and am working on some methods to format these variable's into strings such that the end output will be something along the lines of

*Number: 1234 5678 9012 3456

Expiration date: 10/14

Account holder: Bob Jones

Is valid: true*

(Won't format correctly - I'm unsure how to do it, would be greatful of someone can edit for me :) )

My question is, in the line

```
String shortYear = Integer.toString(expiryYear).substring(2,4);
```

Why won't the following work:

```
toString(argument).substring(2,4)
```

I would have imagined it wound have worked (expiryYear is essentially declared as an instance variable of type int). I've consulted my book (The official Java Tutorial also found online), and can't seem to find anything. I didn't even know about Integer.toString, a friend told me about that after trying to play with toString(), so it would be even more greatly appreciated if someone could also tell me where I can find these sorts of methods (I don't think they're in my book)

```
public class CreditCard {

    private int expiryMonth;
    private int expiryYear;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String ccNumber;

    public CreditCard(int expiryMonth, int expiryYear, String firstName, String lastName, String ccNumber) {
        this.expiryMonth = expiryMonth;
        this.expiryYear = expiryYear;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.ccNumber = ccNumber;
    }

    public String formatExpiryDate() {
        String shortYear = Integer.toString(expiryYear).substring(2, 4);
        String expiryDate = expiryMonth + "/" + shortYear;
        return expiryDate;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CreditCard cc1 = new CreditCard(10, 2014, "Bob", "Jones", "1234567890123456");

        System.out.print(cc1.formatExpiryDate());
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you don't have a `toString` function that takes a parameter.

Comment: You need to define this function toString if you want to use it , it's not like procedural languages(C for example) , it's OOP

Comment: Isn't toString a public method which is part of the object class (which is a superclass to every implemented class) so I should be able to access it? Or am I thinking wrong here?

Comment: fwiw you could use `year % 100` to get the last 2 digits of the year (as an int)

Comment: toString is indeed a method of `object`, but it has no parameters defined.  In order to get it to call the method on `object`, you would have to call it without any parameters, and its behavior would likely be different.

Comment: Here you can find the source code of an open-jdk... just to understand what it does http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.toString%28int%29

Comment: Ah Robert so what you're saying is it operates in a manner such as "someNonStringValue.toString()" and not "toString(someNonStringValue)"?

Dylan - If I use that, I don't think I'll be able to concatenate it to month in order for the program to output the expiry year of the credit card

Answer (score 3):

Try `String.valueOf(expiryYear).substring(2,4)`

Comment: Yay another DBZ fan :D. On topic; thanks for the reply - do you have any sort of link or anything where I can find these sorts of functions? They sure like they could be useful to me.

Comment: @Tazman Oracle documents everything for the core Java classes. If you need something search "Class" java api